# How to compare server time with the predefine time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetime, time

I am making an event application. my question how can I compare server time with the predefined time? That predefined time I will write hardcore into my HTML.

Here's the the code for that but it is not working. 
If server time is matched with the predefine time, Then it should give me an alert "hi".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentTime = new Date()
    var hours = currentTime.getHours()
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()

    if (minutes < 10)
        minutes = "0" + minutes

    var suffix = "AM";
    if (hours >= 12) {
        suffix = "PM";
        hours = hours - 12;
}
    if (hours == 0) {
        hours = 12;
    }

    var val1 = '5.43PM';

    var timecount =  hours + ":" + minutes + " " + suffix;
    console.log(timecount);
    if(timecount == val1) {
        alert('true');  
    }
    else {
        alert('false'); 
    }
</script>


<div class="zone"> 5.06 AM</div>
<div class="zone"> 6.06 AM</div>
<div class="zone"> 6.25 PM</div>
<div class="zone"> 5.03 PM</div>
<div class="zone"> 6.49 PM</div>
<div class="zone"> 8.05 PM</div>
```

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/rushijogle/acwD3/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML and JavaScript are run in the client's browser. In order to compare the time with a server time, you would need to use a server-side language of some sort to output the server's current date and time to the HTML.

Comment: But i am getting server time using javascript . only i want to compare

Comment: This is the point Sean is trying to make. You are not getting the server time, you are getting the client time because JS is run client side and has no concept of the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentTime = new Date()
```

gives you Client machine's time not the server time since JS is a client-side scripting. So you need to change your approach.

As far as client time is concerned, below code should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentTime = new Date()
    var hours = currentTime.getHours()
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()

    if (minutes < 10)
        minutes = "0" + minutes

    var suffix = "AM";
    if (hours >= 12) {
        suffix = "PM";
        hours = hours - 12;
}
    if (hours == 0) {
        hours = 12;
    }

    var val1 = '6.45PM';

    var timecount =  hours + ":" + minutes + " " + suffix;

    if(timecount == val1) {
        alert('true');  
    }
    else {
        alert('false'); 
    }
</script>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/acwD3/2/